# Would there be any performance difference between these 2 IEnumerable<T> codes using foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, ienumerable

```
var effects = this.EffectsRecursive;
foreach ( Effect effect in effects )
{
...
}
```

vs

```
foreach ( Effect effect in this.EffectsRecursive )
{
...
}
```

Comment: Only one way to find out; try it and measure the results. But in this case it seems unlikely that there would be a difference.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I was gonna measure but thought the difference could be misleading like between the two results being inconsistent. So wanted to make sure if they would both exactly do the same thing. To me #2 seems more readable since EffectsRecursive isn't very long.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the foreach operates on the result of the call to `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`, which will get called only once either way.

Comment: Indeed, if the `EffectsRecursive` property getter were accessed more than once in either case, I think we could conclude that something is **very** wrong here.